# Open Link from Bash in Existing Browser Tab

Tags: arch-linux, firefox, chrome, i3

I'm generating markdown previews from the commandline (to a local file in /tmp) and would like to update the preview tab instead of creating a new one.

Firefox has a new tab option but nothing on reusing an existing one

```
 --new-tab <url>    Open <url> in a new tab.
```

I couldn't find anything from Chromium either.

Comment: If the file in /tmp has a constant name, you can refresh the window using the answers in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240497/49439

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks - if there's nothing builtin that is certainly an interesting workaround!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled on using [**browser-sync**](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/).

It's a web server that refreshes the browser whenever a local file changes.

The only issue is a race condition when the output is not ready in time ([at least for now](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1828)).